# Calendar update issues (.ics file)

Tags: outlook, calendar, google-calendar-api, icalendar

I have an ics file that I send the to two participants. I want both to be able to approve, reject or suggest a new location or provide a link to the online meeting, but it seems like only the user who makes the calendar update can see it, but not the other one.

Below is the .ics file.

```
VERSION:2.0
PRODID:-//test//test Calendar//EN
METHOD:REQUEST
BEGIN:VEVENT
UID:f4ad093514495ae4dc5c0aa25443dd1a
DTSTAMP:20210512T190903
DTSTART:20210513T110000Z
DTEND:20210513T120000Z
ORGANIZER;CN="John”:mailto:organizer@gmail.com
ATTENDEE;CUTYPE=INDIVIDUAL;ROLE=REQ-PARTICIPANT;PARTSTAT=NEEDS-ACTION;CN=user1@gmail.com;X-NUM-GUESTS=0:mailto:user1@gmail.com
ATTENDEE;CUTYPE=INDIVIDUAL;ROLE=REQ-PARTICIPANT;PARTSTAT=NEEDS-ACTION;CN=user2@gmail.com;X-NUM-GUESTS=0:mailto:user2@gmail.com
LOCATION:Expert to provide the link
SUMMARY:Appointment
BEGIN:VALARM
TRIGGER:-PT05M
ACTION:DISPLAY
DESCRIPTION:Appointment
END:VALARM
PRIORITY:5
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```